# Adding ReactJS to vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I simply add the react library to my html page using a script tag?

Where can I add the following code so it will be executed?

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, worl151d!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Stack overflow has a Documentation section for things just like this. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/797/getting-started-with-react#t=201704061851145125693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, For that you need to add the reference of `react`, `react-dom` and `babel` in html page, and then directly put the `ReactJs` part inside `script` tag, with type of the `script` as `text/jsx`.

Use these reference for `react`, `react-dom` and `babel`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Don't forgot to add the reference of `babel`, that is required to transpile JSX code to javascript.

Mention the type of the script as `text/jsx`, otherwise babel will no transpile that part.

Check the working example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id='root'/>
     <script type='text/jsx'>
        ReactDOM.render(
           <h1>Hello, worl151d!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
     </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Check these for details:

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/), [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  [Check out the docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn)

It basically says you can add the following script tags to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Please note that in order to use JSX, ES6, you'll have to include the CDN scripts for a [transpiler like Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) too:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

When you gain some momentum that same page offers some simple advice on using a package manager like `npm` or `yarn` to set up your projects

Comment: I installed npm . Please tell me how its helping me for projects. where do I write my code ?